# Atom, search in all the files

Tags: atom-editor

I'm trying to do a complete search through Atom, looking for a specific text.
Well, this sounds very simple, using `Command + Shift + F` but, there the `node_modules` are not tracked and the content inside of those directories are not scanned.
I'm not sure if it is because are untracked files defined by `.gitignore` or the packages are excluded.
How I can do a full search in my opened project?

Comment: I just tested and a project search is searching in `node_modules` for me even though it is in my `.gitignore`.

Comment: Thanks for posting this question, I couldn't find the search in all files feature before!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is probably due to the `Exclude VCS Ignored Paths` setting in Atom's Core settings. Please try the search again after unselecting the respective checkbox in the settings:

[image: Atom Settings]

You can find this setting on the first page of the Atom Settings, a bit down under *Core Settings*.

The setting's description describes what is excluded from functionality like the fuzzy finder and the search and replace function. You're probably running into that at the moment...

Comment: Yes, It works! in mac os, Atom > Preferences > Settings > Uncheck Exclude VCS Ignored Paths and now I have a full seach, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

**For MacOS:**

`Atom` > `Preferences` > `Settings` > uncheck `Exclude VCS Ignored Paths` and now I have a full search and now, you can search through all the files.